# Storing vertices in Java - Mapping Edges

Tags: java, performance, graph, storage

I'm trying to build a graph with vertices, A, B, C & D. The graph must map an edge to a particular vertex if there is an overlap, For instance vertices A and C overlap as A has 1 -> 2, and C has 1 -> 4.

What would be an efficient way of storing these vertices then checking if their values overlap with one another?

Example:

```
A 1 2 3 4  
B 9 10 12 13  
C 1 4 2 3   
D 15 16 17 18
```

Comment: Generally speaking, since little information and examples are provided - sounds like you want to use a `HashSet` or `HashMap`.

Comment: Can you give more example?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how often these graphs are expected to change. If it's just once off, storing the vertex constraint in a `Map<Vertex, Set<Constraint>`, calculating the intersections and then storing the final graph as an adjacency list or matrix is just fine.

You would do something like

```
For each vertex v:
   For each other vertex u
    if constraints(u) intersect constraints(v)
        add edge between u and v
```

You will end up with a symmetric un-directed graph.

Comment: I would later like to add additional information to each vertex, would this change anything?  For instance A : Soccer  - B : Tennis etc.

Comment: Each time you add a new constraint, you will need to sweep over the whole vertex list again. If you are just tacking metadata to a vertex that doesn't change the graph's structure, nothing will change. If you could explain your usecase more, it might be easier to help you.

Comment: How would I define Map<Vertex, Set<Constraint>? It seems it's missing a '>' after Vertex is that right? What is Constraints? is that just a variable or a particular Object?

My usecase - when finding all the edges (overlaps between the integers) then I will need to assign the vertices a sport. Every adjacent vertex must be assigned to a different sport. Hence you can't do the same sport if there is an overlap.